# Select an element's id from PHP loop using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list of `<img>` tags with each of them contains different id. This is done using PHP for loop as shown below:

```
<?php
   for($n=0; $n<=5; $n++)
   {    
?>          
      <img id="<?php echo 'time_'.$n; ?>" src="$output-mp4_thumbnails-$n.jpg">
<?php
   }
?>
```

I want to use jQuery in such a way that, when I click on the specific image on my browser, it would print out the id accordingly. Below is how I code it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
       alert($("img").attr("id"));
    }); 
});
```

However this keeps printing only the first id, which is `time_0`. I have been looking around for ways to solve this, and I found out about `change()`, but it can only be used for form inputs.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nesting php tags `<?php` and `?>`, specifically in the loop.

Try to echo out the image tag as:

```
for($n=0; $n<=5; $n++)
{               
    echo "<img id='time_{$n}' src='{$output}-mp4_thumbnails-{$n}.jpg' />";
}
```

This should generate unique image ids as `time_0`, `time_1` and so on upto `time_5`.  In addition to this, you also need to incorporate either @Arun's answer or @tchow002 answer on the jQuery side as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
       alert(this.id)
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Have been scratching head over this since yesterday. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if there are 2 images with different "id" so how would we select ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `alert($(this).attr("id"));`

`this` will select the `img` that was clicked. Your current code matches the first `img` instead and does not account for what was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem with the alert, you have `alert($("img").attr("id"))` which will always alert the `id` of the first img element, instead you need to alert the id of the clicked element so `alert(this.id)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").click(function () {
       var $id = this.id;
       alert(id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($n=0; $n<=5; $n++) {
    echo sprintf("<img id='time_%d' src='%s-mp4_thumbnails-%d.jpg' />", $n, $output, $n);
}
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.